# How do I mount logical volumes from a VG of hard disks taken from another computer?

Tags: restore, lvm

I have two disks with PVs of a volume group with several logical volumes that was created on another computer.

They were not exported with `vgexport`.

How do I restore the volume group now built into the new computer and mount its logical volumes ?

`vgscan` only finds the new volume group originally created on the new computer; however `pvscan` / `pvdisplay` *do* find all physical volumes.

`vgchange -ay [VG-NAME]` does not find the old volume group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied over `/etc/lvm/backup/[VG-NAME]` from the old disks (or from a backup) to the new system's `/etc/lvm/backup` directory and ran `vgcfgrestore [VG-NAME]` and `vgchange -ay [VG-NAME]`.

Now I'm able to mount the logical volumes.